# Second battery either not charging or charge not detected

Tags: centos, power-management, proc, acpi, battery

I have installed Linux on my laptop and running it as the only system. It displays both batteries on the desktop UI, with the first one on 100% and second 0%.

When it is discharged it just discharge the main one and shuts down when it goes to 0%. This defeats the purpose of having 2 batteries.

I tried to look for battery info under `/proc/acpi/battery/` but found there are no battery directory under `/proc/acpi/`.

I could get some info from `upower`:

```
$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:09/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0
  vendor:               SANYO
  model:                42T4845
  serial:               20914
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat Sep 10 19:25:42 2016 (4 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               fully-charged
    energy:              33.4998 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         33.8439 Wh
    energy-full-design:  43.9893 Wh
    energy-rate:         1.6206 W
    voltage:             12.532 V
    percentage:          98.9833%
    capacity:            76.9367%
    technology:          lithium-ion

$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1
  native-path:          /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:09/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0A:01/power_supply/BAT1
  vendor:               SONY
  model:                51J0508
  serial:               1266
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat Sep 10 19:25:22 2016 (27 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    energy:              0 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         32.4108 Wh
    energy-full-design:  31.32 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    voltage:             11.225 V
    percentage:          0%
    capacity:            10.6897%
    technology:          lithium-polymer
```

Both battery was working nicely while I was running Windows, one gets discharged then the other, and warns me to plug in when only one had charge of about 10%.

The laptop is a Thinkpad T420s running CentOS 7.

Is there some package or driver that I need to install to get both batteries to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have took out the second battery use it with one battery installed now. At least all the power related functions works now, it goes to sleep when it reaches low battery etc... instead of powering off randomly.

I guess Linux just doesn't support secondary battery.